# Requesting feedback on the feasibility of creating a Google Apps Script to modify the default Gmail 'Save As' filename

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I would like to create a means of overriding the default filename generated by Gmail when saving an email as a PDF file. I have a specific naming convention I use. It is tedious to manually modify the default filename each time I want to print an email to PDF.

I would like to create a script that does the following:

1. Within Gmail, I open an email I want to print to PDF.
2. I click a button or select a menu entry to initiate my print to PDF script.
3. The script opens the 'Save As' dialog and populates the filename field following my naming convention.
4. I then take over and interact with the 'Save As' dialog to save the file to the location of my choice.

I have done some initial research, but I am not confident this is going to be easy to accomplish. I would like some feedback from experts as to the feasibility of my project.

Thank you.

Comment: With Apps script, it is possible to create pdfs and rename them and store them in Google drive. It is also possible to provide a download function. But I'm not sure(probably not possible)  whether you can interact with  any inbuilt gmail UI function such as "Save As". Such browser automations, if needed are better  accomplished with browser user scripts using user script managers like `violentmonkey`.

Comment: Create a gmail add-on service.  Add to your gmail, when you open an email it will trigger an event call onload(e).  Get the emailid , get the  attachment as blob.  Using drive service - insert function to move this file to your folder, you can rename the file as you want.

Comment: Above solution requires you to manually process each emails.  Another possible solution will be:   Applied label to those emails, then run a script the get those emails, loop each email and fetch attachments as blob then  insert those files into your folder.  Remove label or change labels.  I have a working solution for service like this.  Let me know if that’s what you need

Comment: @TheMaster, the filename naming convention I mentioned includes the date and time of the email. Therefore, it must be possible to get this information from Gmail. I think this would exclude the use of a browser user script.

Comment: @liquidkat, A manual process is what I’m looking for. I decide which folder to save the PDF file in after I open and read the email. In some cases, I need to create a folder. Is there any service that will open a dialog to request the ‘save to’ folder?

Comment: Gmail add on will be a good option in which you can use a picker service.

Comment: @liquidkat, I investigated your Gmail add on recommendation. I see how it may be possible to create a Google Workspace add-on that will present a user with a button that when activated will convert the currently open email to a PDF blob, open a Drive dialog using the picker service to allow the user to specify where to save the Gmail PDF file, and then save the PDF blob to a file in the specified Drive folder. From what I can gather, the only limitation to this solution is that the Gmail PDF file must be saved to Google Drive. Do you concur?

Comment: @liquidkat, Due to my inexperience with Google Workspace Add-ons, I'm looking for the best way to begin my journey into this brave new world. Do you have any recommendations for gaining the knowledge I need to build a Gmail add on that will solve my problem? I found this codelab example, "Make email more actionable with Google Workspace Add-ons" (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/gmail-add-ons/#0). Do you think this is a good place to start?

Comment: @SLax Yes. The attachment has to be saved on Google Drive

Comment: @SLax https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/cats-quickstart#common.gs This post might help you getting start.

Comment: @liquidkat: Thank you for your help and recommendations. I have also enrolled in this ûdemy course, [Google Apps Script Complete Course New IDE 100+ Examples](https://www.udemy.com/course/course-apps-script/). Hopefully it will teach me some much-needed skills.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the question: you are not trying to interact at the Gmail web application level, but at the browser.

You can check for yourself when you use Gmail: before trying to save your attachment you can open the console (pressing F12) but as soon as you enter in a "save as" menu either you can't open it, or it will be dimmed.

This, again AFAIU, prevents you from acting even at the extension level, because you would not be able to press an extension button while the save dialog is open.

Unless you want to dig into the inner workings of your browser, I would recommend going the route of checking automation scripts for your operating system.

You could create a hot key on your pc that keys in the characters that respect your file format and, as soon as they are keyed in, you would then be able to modify the file name and press Enter.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to differentiate between Gmail web application functionality and browser functionality. Does an Apps Script script interface with the Gmail web application?

I was hoping that an Apps Script script could act like a macro. That I could gather some information from the email to build my filename and then make use of the inherent ‘Save As PDF’ functionality to actually save the email as a PDF. It appears that it is a bit more complicated.

I experimented with the console, but I don't understand it well enough to make any informed decisions.

Comment: I’ve seen examples where an Apps Script script is used to convert an email into a PDF blob. But I haven’t found any examples where an Apps Script script is used to open a ‘Save as’ dialog to query the user for where to save the PDF blob as a file.
If it is possible to have an Apps Script script open a ‘Save as’ dialog, then I think I may be able to code a script that will do what I need.

Comment: Google's App Script is a layer on top of the browser, your pc's OS, your hw on your side; on Google's servers/applications on their side. It is a glue that leverages services to provide you with other services. When it needs to interact with something, e.g. your pc to save a file, it calls one of the browser's APIs, asks it to save, the browser calls the pc's API to get access to the file system and calls the windows API of your pc. But it's the browser that opens the windows, not Apps Scripts. You want to change stuff that is out of Apps Scripts reach. Again, AFAIU the problem.

Comment: As highlighted in the comments below your question, you could paradoxically create an Apps Script that automatically saves your attachments in your Google Drive which you could map to a location on your pc, btw. You could also alter their names and choose the directory, but I doubt you can alter the manual process, because Apps Script is not a macro that can key in text inside a browser's dialog.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My problem is a simple one. Perhaps I obscured it with an overcomplicated question. Basically, all I want to do is modify the default 'Save as' filename to include the sent/received time in UTC time and 'Sent' or 'Received' depending on whether the email was sent or received, respectively. But, because the default 'Save as' filename is not configurable, I was hoping I could solve my problem with an Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you for trying to explain where Google's Apps Script lies in the grand scheme of layers. I'm sure it's an in-depth topic. It's hard to know where to start trying to learn about the idiosyncrasies of such a system. It is difficult to know what is unachievable due to the architecture and what is unachievable simply because the necessary support has not been incorporated into the software. For example, the Gmail app can save to the local file system using available browser functionality. It seems logical that Apps Script could support that same functionality.